# Getting response from facebook login button

Tags: facebook-login

I am having problem in getting response from facebook login button.
And will be very thankful for any instant help.
I am using following code:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=MY_APP_ID";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>

<div class="fb-login-button" data-show-faces="false" data-width="200" data-max-rows="1"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
    if(response.status=="connected")
    {
        document.getElementById("fblogin").value=response.authResponse.userID;
    }

});
</script>
```

... but I am getting the error in my javascript console  : "FB is not fefined " and no alert message for auth responeId is recieved to me.

Please help its very important

Answer (score 2):

Or if you want to still load the JS SDK async style, you can wire up your event handlers in the window.FbAsyncInit() like such:

```
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
          appId      : 'YOUR_APP_ID', // App ID
          channelUrl : '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // Channel File
          status     : true, // check login status
          cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
          xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
      });

      // Additional initialization code here
      FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
          if(response.status=="connected")
          {
            document.getElementById("fblogin").value=response.authResponse.userID;
          }
      });

  };

<script>

(function(d, s, id) { var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];

  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=MY_APP_ID";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
<div class="fb-login-button" data-show-faces="false" data-width="200" data-max-rows="1">
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript">

FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
    if(response.status=="connected")
    {
        document.getElementById("fblogin").value=response.authResponse.userID;
    }

});

</script>
```

You can see this style (which is Facebook's preferred style) documented here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

Answer (score -1):

You are loading facebook javascript sdk asynchronously through following code

```
<div id="fb-root"></div> 
<script>(function(d, s, id) { var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];

  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=MY_APP_ID";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

So, your FB is not defined until it gets loaded.

Try loading FB syncronously. Put following code and remove the above one,

```
<script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
  FB.init({
    appId      : 'YOUR_APP_ID',
    status     : true, // check login status
    cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
  });
</script>
```